# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002 noMatchError

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, routes

I have this error when I try to navigate to a specific path
[Message Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuVvs.png)

I try to navigate to the route "customer/detail" in this two ways:

1. in the html by clicking a button `routerLink="customer/detail/"`
2. calling a method `this.router.navigate(['customer/detail', data.Id]);`

But in both I have the same error.

My routingModule is this:

```
export const customersRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: CustomerListComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'detail/:ID',
                component: CustomerDetailComponent,
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(customersRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class CustomerRoutingModule { }
```

This routingmodule is imported in this module (CustomerModule):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    NgxDatatableModule,
    CustomerRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [CustomerDetailComponent, CustomerListComponent]
})
export class CustomersModule { }
```

The customermodule is imported in the AppModule and is used in the AppRouting:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'customer',
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'customer', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule) },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'phone-call', component: PhoneCallComponent },
      { path: 'settings', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsModule) },
      { path: 'real-estates', component: RealEstateListComponent },
      { path: 'real-estate/:id', component: RealEstateEditComponent },
      { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard'
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
      initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking'
      // relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy'
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: Are you providing the id of the customer in the routerLink?

Comment: @MartaMolinari, once you have over 10 reputation you will be able to put images in your question.  That being said, you obviously can't do that currently, but I do recommend you take the time to enter in the image description. Take care, and welcome to the community. 

Comment: @Johalternate Yes, but the error still appear, It appear also if I put in the routerLink another path for esample --> `routerLink="dashboard"`

Comment: @MartaMolinari can you provide a Stackblitz?

Comment: @Johalternate https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynit8f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts It's my first Stackblitz, I hope is correct

Comment: @MartaMolinari you should revise the hierarchy of the routing module, right now you have customers details as a child of the customer list, they should be siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add slash at the beginning of string? `routerLink="/customer/detail/"`. If you don't the link is considered as relative to active routing - so if you dashboard page you are trying to go to `/dashboard/customer/detail/:id`

Please try using lowercase for `:id` token:

```
{
  path: 'detail/:id',
  component: CustomerDetailComponent,
}
```

not: `path: 'detail/:ID'` - to work with uppercase I thing you should use `[routerLink]="['/customer/detail', {ID: data.Id}]"` then url in browser would look like this `/customer/detail/;ID=3`. Here are docs for that: https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#navigate-to-crisis-list-with-a-relative-url

Comment: Yes, but It doesn't change the result. The problem is also when search the path "customer/detail/2" in the browser it doesn't work